# JavaScript image resize slowness

Tags: php, javascript, html, image, resize

A site I am working on has a lot of images that are pulled from a database. The dimensions of the images are not consistent and I am trying to display them in uniformly sized boxes (divs). I do not know the dimensions of any of the images but I can retrieve them with:

```
document.getElementById( myImage ).width
document.getElementById( myImage ).height
```

After this I do my tests to see how to resize images to fit the uniform boxes. Finally I set the effects with:

```
document.getElementById( myImage ).width = theNewWidth
document.getElementById( myImage ).height = theNewHeight
```

This function is only called once per image by using `onload="resizingFunction( imgId );"` in the img tag. It takes about 1-2 seconds for every image in the database to complete this function and the function is never run for any of those images again. Despite never running again, the site runs significantly slower if I use this function. After googling I tried adding:

```
document.getElementById( myImage ).removeAttribute("width")
document.getElementById( myImage ).removeAttribute("height")
```

Before setting the new width and height. This did improve the speed but it is still slower than if I had not resized the images. Again, just for clarification, each image is resized one time after it has been loaded but for some reason this still slows down the site.

Images are created by being PHP echoed into JavaScript. This is necessary because they need information from the database (PHP), and the JavaScript places them inside the correct box (div). Here is the creation of image code:

```
echo "\t\t\tdocument.getElementById('gBox".$i."').innerHTML = '<img onload=\"image_applyToGrid(".$i.");\" id=\"img".$i."\" style=\"left:0; top:0;\" src=\"'+gBoxes[".$i."].imgPath+'\"/>';\n";
```

Here is the image resizing function that images call once onload:

```
function image_applyToGrid(inId) {
inIdImage = document.getElementById("img"+inId);
var imgW = inIdImage.width;
var imgH = inIdImage.height;
if (imgW > imgH) {
    var proportions = imgW/imgH;
    imgH = gridUnit;
    imgW = gridUnit*proportions;
    inIdImage.style.left = -((imgW-gridUnit)>>1)+"px";
}
else {
    var proportions = imgH/imgW;
    imgW = gridUnit;
    imgH = gridUnit*proportions;
    inIdImage.style.top = -((imgH-gridUnit)>>1)+"px";
}
inIdImage.removeAttribute("width");
inIdImage.removeAttribute("height");
inIdImage.width = imgW;
inIdImage.height = imgH;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you resize the images on the server side? Loading many large images has impact on performance. You say the function is never run an image again, but it looks like it is always run on page load and it does not seem you are changing the actual size of an image and store it somewhere.

Comment: Have you tried a CSS solution? Have a container wrapping the images setting them both css `max-width` and `max-height` property?

Comment: You can serve the images through PHP and include an additional size parameter in the URL. If the image of that size exists, serve it. If not, load the original image, resize it and store the resized version. This should not be too complicated to do...

Comment: I found the problem, it was that the PHP echo wrote the information to JavaScript and using JavaScript to write innerHTML is apparently slower than just writing it as normal HTML. I just relocated the PHP echo to be inside <body> and had it echo HTML instead

Comment: Never mind, that still is not as fast as it is supposed to be. I guess what I am wondering is why using the width and height attributes slow down the site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Resizing images with Javascript is generally not an ideal approach.  You are consuming all of the bandwidth to send the full size images across the web and then scaling them down.  A better way would be to pull the images from your image store and resize them server side.  Then store the result in a server side cache so you can provide all of your client requests with the optimized images.  No need to over think the concept of cache here, in this case it could be as simple as a directory or a new column in your database. (FWIW, I prefer not to store binary data in databases but that's probably another discussion)

See: http://www.white-hat-web-design.co.uk/blog/resizing-images-with-php/

Answer (score 0):

The images are probably much too large.  I would suggest preparing the images for web use.  Google "optimizing images for web" for some ideas on how to do this.

Comment: Not an option unfortunately. Also, the majority of the images are very, very small as they are old. Most of the images are smaller than 150x150 which is what I proportionately expand them to (hiding the parts that stick out of the box with overflow:hidden).

Answer (score 0):

It's bad practice to take full-size images and load the entire image at different dimensions. Consider having thumbnails generated and placed on the page.

If you have a 2500x2500 image that you're just setting the height and width to 500x500, the entire 2500x2500 image is still having to be loaded.

Comment: It is more of the opposite problem in general. Most of the images are too small and I want to expand them to be at least 150x150 (hiding the sections of the image that stick out with overflow:hidden if they are not square).